# Is there a way to solve a type declaration that accepts a union of a string and a function?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, type-declaration, type-definition

I've this type definition, incomplete at the moment:

```
export type Type1 = string;

export type Type2 = string | { [index: string]: any } | Array<string | undefined | boolean>;

export type Type3 = { [index: string]: any } | Array<string | undefined | boolean>;

export type Type4 = (arg1?: Type2 | Type3, arg2?: Type3) => string | undefined;

export default function myLibrary(arg1?: Type1, arg2?: Type2, arg3?: Type3): Type4;
```

Normally the library is used in scenarios like the one of the following example, types declaration works properly in this example, within React application:

```
const myCustomLibrary = myLibrary('string')
...
<span className={myCustomLibrary({
  key: value
})}/>
```

where `value` can be anything like a boolean, string, object..

But I said incomplete definition because it is not covering the following scenario, still within a React application:

```
<span className={myLibrary('string', {
  key: value
})}/>
```

Basically `myLibrary` can return a function or also a string, depending of the values received as input according to a specific internal logic. So the type `Type4` could also be a string, not only a method returning a string. Current type declaration offers just the type `Type4` as output, it misses a simple string. In fact while returning a string, here is the error:

```
TS2322: Type 'Type4' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

So I thought to add a string to the return value of `myLibrary`

```
export default function myLibrary(arg1?: Type1, arg2?: Type2, arg3?: Type3): Type4 | string;
```

but this ruins other scenarios currently working (the one receiving the actual `Type4` and it gives this error

```
Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'string | Type4' has no compatible call signatures.ts(2349)
```

Feel in a loophole, what am I doing wrong?
I could solve everything defining `Type4` as `any`, but that is not what I want to achieve.

Comment: We can't help you without seeing the type declarations. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally accompanied by a link to the same code on the [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) showing the problem. (But ensure the entire code is **in** the question as well.)

Comment: I thought these other types were not relevant, but I added them anyway. Do you think it is enough?

Comment: Are you looking for changing the return type of a function according to the input parameters? If so, have a look at overloads

Comment: @axel - Those help, but please see my comment above. A complete example that demonstrates the problem without our having to guess at things (like what `value` is) helps people help you.

Comment: Unluckily I am using a third party library written in javascript, so I can't change source code. I want to have just types in place.

Comment: the problem is in the output of this function `myLibrary` I don't see why it is relevant something happening inside, that `value` for example is a value that can assume multi types, and it is used in the logic of `myLibrary` to define the output, but it is not relevant for the question I assume.

Comment: Overloads will help here. It is still not clear when the string should be returned and when the function https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvKBrCIBcUDOwATgJYB2A5lAL4DcAUPQCYQDGANgIZHQBmArmVbAScMlAC2IADIkARkW4gAFLwR54cAJR5CpSgxYdufQcNHipshUuVhunCbuLkKAGihq4GhDoIuDZjYuHk8zETFJGXlFIhV7RSd-fXcoBMcAJmcUj3SJAGZs1z9lLWQAPmTXBnp2CGAoHnx+dgaUKxjbdCxcKAByHr6aMoB6EarKeiaWtqjrWJU+vT6Pbuw8Aewh6lHxvVdGVjFCRohm1ozkOc645SXiFf7lj3uiPt2woQiyIA

Comment: I check overloads. Come back to you, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is indeed the usage of **Overloads** concept, thanks @AlekseyL. for the tip in the comments, for clearer reference I add here the proper code fix.

```
export default function myLibrary(arg1?: Type1, arg2?: Type1): Type4;

export default function myLibrary(arg1: Type1, arg2: Type3 | undefined): string;

export default function myLibrary(arg1: Type1, arg2: Type2, arg3: Type3): string;
```